How to control the background process in scripts run through make?
I have a Makefile with the following content:
MAKEFLAGS += -s
SHELL := /bin/bash

all:
    $(MAKE) step1
    $(MAKE) -j 2 step2 step3
    $(MAKE) step4

step1:
    $(MAKE) step1_execute

step1_execute:
    echo "Running step 1..."
    ./createFileWithTime.sh output/step1_output
    echo "step1 completed."

step2:
    $(MAKE) step2_execute

step2_execute:
    echo "Running step 2..."
    ./createFileWithTime.sh output/step2_output
    echo "step2 completed."

step3:
    $(MAKE) step3_execute

step3_execute:
    echo "Running step 3..."
    ./createFileWithTime.sh output/step3_output
    echo "step3 completed."

step4:
    $(MAKE) step4_execute

step4_execute:
    echo "Running step 4..."
    ./createFileWithTime.sh output/step4_output
    echo "step4 completed."

Script createFileWithTime.sh looks like this:
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <filename>"
    exit 1
fi

file_path="$1"
dir_name=$(dirname "$file_path")

if [ ! -d "$dir_name" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$dir_name"
fi

current_date=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%N")

echo "$current_date" > "$file_path"

sleep 3 &

echo "File '$file_path' created with current date and time: $current_date"

The problem is that the script runs the sleep 3 command in the background, which causes the Makefile to continue executing steps until all processes are completed. For example, when I run make all, I see that the output files were not created with a 3-second delay.
How can I make Makefile wait for the completion of all script commands, including those that are launched in the background, given that I cannot modify the scripts themselves?
P.S. I want to mention that I cannot specify prerequisites for my targets and must use a combination of <step_name> and <step_name>_execute targets to execute the steps, for reasons that would be too lengthy to explain.

Can't you just put a wait command at the end of your createFileWithTime.sh script?  Or have I missed the point?

@G.M. Unfortunately, I can't edit scripts.

Can you edit the makefile?  If so you could have a new bash script that does something like . createFileWithTime.sh "$@"; wait and replace createFileWithTime.sh in the makefile with calls to the new script.

As a general comment: you have a makefile with several targets, none of which have any prerequisites.  That combined with the rather 'awkward' nature of your script suggests all of this might be better achieved with a more general programming language rather than a makefile.

The short simple answer to your direct question is, you can't.  There's no way I'm aware of to write a makefile recipe that will wait for backgrounded processes started by some script the recipe invokes, if you can't modify that script at all.  Only that script knows what processes it created and you can't wait for them to complete unless you have the PID of those processes.  If the script doesn't tell you the PID, you can't wait for it.

BTW just to be clear: this is all related to shell scripts.  It has nothing to do with make at all.  If you can write a shell script that will behave the way you want then you can write a makefile recipe (which is just a shell script) to do it as well.  If you can't, you can't.

If you know enough details about the commands that the script backgrounds you can, of course, write some scripting that waits for it; for example using ps to show all the processes running on the system and wait for the ones you care about to be finished (no longer shown in the output).

What's the point of running sleep in the background in the first place?  That seems utterly counterproductive, make or no make.
